# bash split file chunks to array

Tags: bash

I have the command to split the file in to chunks of  2 lines
split -l 2  `urls.txt`

It creates some random files.
I have a scenario when I want to split the `urls.txt` into 2 lines chunks much like php str_split, and loop each 5 line block.

so if `urls.txt` is:

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
example4.com
example5.com
```

the splitted array would be

```
array
0 {
example1.com
example2.com
}

1 {
example3.com
example4.com
}

2 {
example5.com
}
```

I use head -5 urls.txt
But I dont know how to loop it and increase every n numbers

Comment: you should think about this and dice this question into solvable steps then do research on each step

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you will need a combination of both `tail` and `head`, or another tool like `sed`. Considering you want to stick with `tail` and `head`, you could do:

```
tail -n +${first_line} | head -n ${number_of_lines}
```

In `man 1 tail` you find the `-n` parameter:

```
-n, --lines=[+]NUM
          output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use 
          -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

So, `tail -n +10` will print everything starting from the 10th line of the file. Just increment `${first_line}` as you must and set the correct `${number_of_lines}`.

If this is not fast enough to your use case, you should have a look at `man 1 sed`. Using `sed`, you can accomplish the same as above using:

```
sed ${first_line},+${number_of_lines}\!d
```

What you are asking to `sed` is to remove all lines of the input except for the lines ranging from `${first_line}` to `${first_line} + ${number_of_lines}`.